# Django REST Framework: DRY way to specify viewmodels

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to have a clear way for declaring a viewmodel for my Django REST endpoints, which the incoming requests must adhere to and which would take care of the validation. I mean something like viewmodels in Spring or other Java projects.

The most primitive way is just to work with the `request.data` (or `request.POST`) dictionary-like object, but in this case all the validation is hardcoded to the view layer.

A little better approach would be to use serializers, but using them is still quite verbose and in the end you get back a `dict`, unless you implement the `.create()` method witch makes the code even more verbose. Here is my current approach:

```py
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer= MySerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        what_i_actually_need = serializer.validated_data
        ...
        return Response('Something')
```

Is there a more DRY way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the Spring approach I implemented something similar. Let me first show the public API and then include the code behind it.

```py
class GreetingViewModel(ViewModel):
    first_name= serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name= serializers.CharField(max_length=120)

class GreetingView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # ViewModel will be validated here 
        viewmodel = GreetingViewModel.get_viewmodel(request.data)

        return Response({'message': f'Good afternoon, '
                         'dear {viewmodel.first_name} {viewmodel .last_name}!'})
```

And here is the code behind it:

```py
class ViewModel(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Used to strictly specify a viewmodel expected from the request body.
    Call `get_viewmodel` to convert request body to a Python object after it is validated.
    """

    @classmethod
    def get_viewmodel(cls, data):
        instance = cls(data=data)
        instance.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return instance.save()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        obj = type('ViewModel', (), validated_data)()
        return obj
```

Note that this is just my personal idea, so I appreciate comments and suggestions.